# Loading the correct gem version error LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano

I am trying to run a capistrano update: `cap production deploy`

But I get the error: `cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rails
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/releases/20151214160634/Capfile:7:in`require'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/releases/20151214160634/Capfile:7:in `<top (required)>'`

Here it is with `--trace`

```
$cap production deploy --trace
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rails
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/releases/20151214160634/Capfile:7:in `require'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/releases/20151214160634/Capfile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I believe there is an issue with the version of capistrano, so I uninstalled it and tried it with '2.15' but that version gives the same error.

Capistrano is defined in my Gemfile like this:

```
...
group :development do
    gem 'capistrano',         require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
    gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
...
```

**EDIT 1**

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

gives:

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:292:in `block in replace_gem': capistrano is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/deploy/apps/my-web-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT 2**

I moved the capistrano lines in the gemfile outside of the group and ran `rvmsudo bundle install`.

Now `bundle exec cap production deploy gives`:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
config/deploy/production.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bundle exec cap production deploy` to ensure that the gems declared in your Gemfile are being used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see edit 1, it gave me that error

Comment: Looks like your original question has been solved, right?